# C++/ vector of class instances as property of another class

Tags: c++, arduino, stdvector

I'm trying to create class (PgWeightTestItemSet), that has private property _testItems. The _testItems is a std::vector of instances of another class (PgWeightTestItem).

Header for PgWeightTestItem is included in PgWeightTestItemSet.h.

After i'm code check in Arduino IDE there is an error:

`error: 'PgWeightTestItem' was not declared in this scope
     std::vector <PgWeightTestItem> _testItems;`

So my questions are:

- is that possible to declare vector of class instances as property of another class
- if it's possible, what i'm doing wrong?

The code is bellow:

**PgWeightTestItemSet.h**

```
#ifndef PgWeightTestItemSet_h
#define PgWeightTestItemSet_h

#include "Arduino.h"
#include <PgWeightTestItem.h>

class PgWeightTestItemSet {

public:
    PgWeightTestItemSet(std::vector<float> & referenceAv, std::vector<float> & referenceMin, std::vector<float> & referenceMax, bool cumulative);

    /*other public properties and methods*/

private:       
    std::vector <PgWeightTestItem> _testItems;

    /*other private properties and methods*/
};

#endif
```

**PgWeightTestItem.h**

```
#ifndef PgWeightTestItem_h
#define PgWeightTestItem_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class PgWeightStandards {

public:
    PgWeightStandards(float & referenceAv, float & referenceMin, float & referenceMax);

    /*public properties*/

private:
    /*private properties*/
};

#endif
```

**Arduino_project.ino**

```
#include <PgWeightTestItemSet.h>
//other arduino code bellow
```

**Directory structure**

```
/root/
/root/Projects/ArduinoProject/Arduino_project.ino
/root/libraries/PgWeightTestItem/
/root/libraries/PgWeightTestItem/PgWeightTestItem.h
/root/libraries/PgWeightTestItem/PgWeightTestItem.cpp
/root/libraries/PgWeightTestItemSet/
/root/libraries/PgWeightTestItem/PgWeightTestItemSet.h
/root/libraries/PgWeightTestItem/PgWeightTestItem.cpp
```

Comment: Your class is called PgWeightStandards not PgWeightTestItem

Comment: ... making this question essentially about a typo

Comment: @Andrew To clarify, The header your including (PgWeightTestItem.h) contains a class called PgWeightStandards , not PgWeightTestItem

Comment: Yes... I haven't noticed this. I'll fix it and return back

Comment: Yes, the mistake in class name is the reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you are defining in PgWeightTestItem.h is called `PgWeightStandards` and not `PgWeightTestItem`. By renaming one of them you should be fine. PgWeightTestItem.h could be as follows:

```
#ifndef PgWeightTestItem_h
#define PgWeightTestItem_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class PgWeightTestItem {

public:
    PgWeightTestItem(float & referenceAv, float & referenceMin, float & referenceMax);

    /*public properties*/

private:
    /*private properties*/
};

#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so simple mistake but when don't know is it possible or not, some time difficult to recognise.